# Generate random number - seed changes only once

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I generate a number in verilog between 0 to 10000 inside a loop like this:

```
wire rand;
integer i, seed;
initial 
   begin
      i=1;
      seed=0;
      while (i<10)
        begin
        force rand = $random(seed) % 10000;
      end
   end
```

the problem that seed changes only once and in the rest of the iterations stays the same. (I see the values in ModelSim).

Comment: so you are setting the seed to zero, not making any changes to it and wondering why it isn't changing?

Comment: I understand that $random is the same as $dist_uniform(seed,0,1000) and in this way the seed changes every iteration. I tried the same code with force rand = $dist_uniform(seed,0,1000) and the result is the same. the real problem is that rand stay the same in every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

It should work with some minor modifications, random number wider than 1 bit if required and do not execute in 0 time. A for loop would be better than a while loop here.

```
integer i, seed;
reg [31:0] rand;

initial begin
  seed=0;
  for(i=0; i<10; i=i+1) begin
    rand = $random(seed) % 10000;
    $display("rand %d", rand);
    #1ns; //Stop loop executing in 0 time
  end
end
```

Comment: the problem is that i want rand to be a wire, not an integer.

Comment: Why? You are defining it from an `initial` block thats what regs are for. `integer` is almost the same as `reg[31:0]` and that can drive inputs.

Comment: I have changed the answer to be a `reg`. This might do what you want unless the force was for a different level of hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need some kind of delay inside that loop? AFAIK it would just iterate through all 10 iterations instantaneously, and would just end up forcing `rand` to the final generated value.

Also, where are you incrementing `i`? Or did you just trim that out before pasting the code?

Comment: you are right. i have in the code i=i+1.
i found out that if i print $display("%d", $random) it prints different values, but if i print: force rand = $random, and then $display("%d", rand) it prints the same values.